# Click event punches through to the <html> element?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, internet-explorer-8, jquery-events

To put it simply:

```
jQuery("html").click(function(e){
    if (e.target == this){
        alert("this really shouldn't happen");
    }
});
```

On IE8, the alert is triggered numerous places on the page, including elements nested inside other elements! Is there anything that would cause such weird behavior?

This is a major issue since this causes the click events to bypass all handlers bound to elements inside the document, instead triggering directly on the document itself (**directly**, not delegated).

**EDIT**

I also suspected something was up when using Developer Tools on IE8... when I would use the "select element by click" tool and hover over the places in question, it would "box" the entire document, as if there were no descendants at that location (and yes, I clicked Refresh to make sure Dev Tools had an up to date schema of the document).

**EDIT 2**

Sorry I forgot to mention... one of these trouble spots is a "dl" element... maybe IE8 gets confused by these and just hands off the event to the document?

Comment: I'm well aware of what event bubbling is... however, e.target represents the initial element that was clicked, NOT the element bound to the handler (see http://api.jquery.com/event.target/). If e.target and "this" are equal, it means that the handler was triggered by a click on the bound element, NOT a descendant.

Comment: Interesting. Buggy. Does the same thing happen if you use `e.stopImmediatePropagation()`? Not saying you should need it, just wondering if it's a workaround to the bug.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the differences in event "bubbling" and event "capturing".

This page explains it well: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html

Comment: I highly doubt this is it, since other places on the page behave normally, and jQuery (supposedly) normalizes bubbling/capturing. But thank you for the link.

Comment: @Matt: jQuery cannot do much here. It only binds event handlers in the bubbling phase. IE simply does not support capturing. That said, I don't think this is related to your issue.